# Cat6e Lan Ethernet Cable - Disconnect when shake in Gigabit Mode. But it is stable when shake in Megabit mode

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

I have some problem in network connection. When I shake the lan cable at the wall jack, the connect will disconnect sometimes if the network is running in 1Gbps. But when it ran in 100mpbs, there is no problem in the stability.

The network connection is as below:

RT2600ac (Main Router) -> Gigabit Unmanaged Switch (Main Swithc) -> TP Link Unmanaged Switch (The switch in the video) -> end user computer

When the cable ran into 1Gbps mode, the connection drop when I shake the lan cable at wall jack. And it will return to 1Gbps connection if I keep shaking.
If the lan cable keep on at the problematic position for a while, the connection will changed from 1Gbps -> 100mbps. If it is ran at 100mbps, no matter how many time I shake, it has no problem in connection, but just keep in the 100mbps mode:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/NwuQYG5hwyJKbD4m7

I try to plug the lan cable into 100 Mbps port, the connection have no problem when I keep shaking the cable at wall jack: https://photos.app.goo.gl/n1r8bvP4taacpCz59

I used tester to test the wire connect. The light switch in sequence of 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8. And even when I keep shaking the cable at the wall jack, it has no problem: https://photos.app.goo.gl/CcNww5wSS2QZwuUv8

The wall jack photo: https://photos.app.goo.gl/TeF81uob98p85Chz7
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The RJ45 jack in the Main Router End is here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/VjyWXx2agHqNjE1v6
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I try changed the main switch to another switch, the problem is the same. I keep debug every part but really ran out of idea. May I know if any expert have any idea how I can fix my gigabit network instability issue? Thanks million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I know if any expert have any idea how I can fix my gigabit network instability issue?

Re-terminate the connections following sane specifications.

This is shitty workmanship, and leads to problems such as the one you experience. It's not within spec, due to mantle being removed over long distance and un-twisting of pairs.

Comment: Omg, it really works! I have this problem for 7 years! You save my life, thank you so much!